# React - Styling not being compiled when running npm run build

Tags: reactjs, webpack

For the first time I've ran `npm run build` and uploaded to my server.

I realised that there wasn't any styling being pulled through very quickly and that it isn't even being referenced in my index.html file.

This is all working great on my dev setup when I run `npm start`

This is my production config and I'm wondering if there is anything obvious to why this isn't running.

https://jsfiddle.net/vmt20f8w/

I should point out that I am using SCSS files instead of css and importing them into my component js files. I thought the webpack.config.prod.js would have then taken all of these scss files and compile them down to one css file?

Update

I've now updated my config with the below code and it still isn't compiling the scss.

```
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"]
            }
        }]
      },
```

To make this even more clear I've actually got a public repo in which people can view all my code to understand the problem:
https://github.com/maximus-lynn/react-portfolio

Comment: In your config you have "test: /\.css$/" instead of "test: /\.scss$/"... not sure if this is the error. I'm webpack beginner ^^

Comment: ha im also a webpack beginner

Comment: try without the options

Comment: nope even without the options it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loader for css files, but not for your scss files. Install sass-loader and change your config to look something like this: 

`test: /\.scss/,
loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'`

Comment: @MaxwellLynn ok, it is a bit hard to tell without seeing the whole project. Might be something with the import of the stylesheet into the project that doesn't match the bundled files, but your webpack config contains allot of stuff I think can be simplified to make a minimal project (assuming it is pretty early in development since you ran npm run build for the first time) You can [have a look at my example](https://github.com/djdifee/home/blob/master/webpack.config.js) for a config I recently posted, might find something.

Comment: ah thanks I'll check it out. I have updated my question with acess to all my code i've written btw.

Comment: so tempted to just write a script to compile every scss file into one then import it into the html file manually

Comment: where I can add this?